# Hanging light from pancake junction box

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, junction-box

I’ve been slowly replacing the light fixtures in my home, and each one is completely unique (the joys of owning an old home).

I’m not seeing a spot to mount the crossbar on my new fixture to in the junction box. The previous fixture was screwed into the ceiling. I feel like I’m missing some sort of bracket, but after doing a bunch of online research, I’m still not finding what I need.

This seems pretty straightforward and it’s driving me crazy. Linking a few pics and hoping someone can direct me in the right direction.

https://share.icloud.com/photos/020KXVRVI5b5aEM2wpacF6ZPw
https://share.icloud.com/photos/0d5YpWzTQGcc_yj_GNqEkqFDw